# Hover on position fixed image

Tags: css, hover, css-position

I have an image that I set up with the position: fixed CSS attribute. I want to change the image source when I hover it with the mouse. The problem is the hover function is called not only when the mouse is on the image but when the mouse enters the invisible square going from x=0, y=0 to the image itself.

I am afraid not to be very clear, here is a JSFiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/fz0e8nz9/1/

How can I manage to change the source only when the mouse hovers the image itself ? Do you have any idea ? Thank you.

HTML code :

```
<body>
        <img src="http://www.geekchamp.com/upload/symbolicons/animals/1f424-chicken.png" id="chicken" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.geekchamp.com/upload/symbolicons/animals/1f423-chick.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.geekchamp.com/upload/symbolicons/animals/1f423-chicken.png'"/>
        <img src="http://www.geekchamp.com/upload/symbolicons/animals/1f423-chick.png" id="chick"/>
</body>
```

CSS code :

```
html
{ 
  background: #dddddd;
}

#chicken
{
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 70%;
    padding-top: 25%;
    width: 15%;
}

#chick
{
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 65%;
    padding-top: 29%;
    width: 10%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `margin`instead of `padding`like this:

```
#chicken
{
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 70%;
    margin-top: 25%;
    width: 15%;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz0e8nz9/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

CSS positioning accepts top -left -bottom -right attributes to move your item, try:

```
position:fixed
left:70%;
top:25%;
width:auto
```